# How to make a generic interfaces in dao classes

Tags: java, generics, model-view-controller, interface, dao

i have 3 equals interfaces with equals methods, but it returns different value depends on entity. 
I have the same interfaces methods in this three classes (Teacher, Group, Student).

**I offer to look a GroupDao interface example.**

```
public interface GroupDao {
    void add(Group group);
    List<Group> getGroupsList();
    void update(Group group);
    Group findById(Long groupId);
    void delete(Long groupId);
}
```

**And i want to combine it for one interface like**

```
public interface EntitiesDao {
    void add({generic} entity);
    List<{generic}> getList();
    void update({generic} entity);
    {generic} findById(Long entityId);
    void delete(Long entityId);
}
```

How can i do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you should use generics.

```
public interface EntitiesDao<T> 
{
    void add(T entity);
    List<T> getList();
    void update(T entity);
    T findById(Long entityId);
    void delete(Long entityId);
}
```